# Set up new extensions in Keycloak kubernetes helm charts

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Azure, where I use Helm to make it easier to manage micro-services and other tools on it, and Keycloak is one of them.

I need to use magic link authenticator in one of my apps, I'm aware that I need to add an extension in my Keycloak chart, but I don't know how.

In the image [repository](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak) I'm using, they explain how to add custom themes, via *extraInitContainers* param on chart configuration. I think I can achieve what I want through it.

In this [tutorial](https://github.com/stianst/keycloak-experimental/tree/master/magic-link) they say that's the extension, but I have no idea how to add this to my Keycloak instance on k8s by using helm charts. How do I achieve that?

Just more info about my config, I'm running louketo-proxy(as a side car) on some apps where I want to protect.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing for implementing custom user storage SPI for local user login in Keycloak. What should be the mountPath? I am using helm charts same as the above-mentioned repository, but how do I know where all the providers are stored? Cannot find much info on Keycloak documentation.

Comment: Also, do we really need to put jar file over maven for local development? I am trying to write a copy script but that's failing too.

Answer (score 2):

To publish a theme with original image, first [create an archive with the thema](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#deploying-themes).

Create a file `custom-themes-values.yml` with a content:

```
extraInitContainers: |
  - name: theme-provider
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command:
      - sh
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        echo "wgetting theme from maven..."
        wget -O /theme/keycloak-theme.jar  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/acme/keycloak-theme/1.0.0/keycloak-theme-1.0.0.jar
    volumeMounts:
      - name: theme
        mountPath: /theme

extraVolumeMounts: |
  - name: theme
    mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments

extraVolumes: |
  - name: theme
    emptyDir: {}
```

Run with:

```
helm install keycloak codecentric/keycloak --values custom-themes-values.yml
```

ps: This example the theme was publish into maven repository, but you can copy a local file to.

This way you can adapt to magic-link.